# MS Word: remove "page break before" for one instance of heading?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, styles

I've got a heading level where I want a page break before each new section *except* for two instances of about a hundred.  I'd like to avoid creating a new heading style for these exceptions.  Is it possible to remove or override the "page break before" for just these two specific headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

Your heading style can have "page break before" set. But there is nothing to stop you then changing this for a specific paragraph in the Paragraph dialog box.

This is no different from changing type size or line spacing.